# Can not set property of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I just can't figure it out why my html is not working. I have just clone the angular-seed from the github and trying to make some changes to learn more about angular.

**view2.js**

```
.controller('View2Ctrl', [function($scope) {
  $scope.message='hello every one';
}]);
```

i have just added a single line of code $scope.message and i have call the message in `view2.html`

**view2.html**

```
<p>This is the partial for view 2.</p>
<h1>hello</h1>
<p>{{message}}</p>
<p>
  Showing of 'interpolate' filter:
  {{ 'Current version is v%VERSION%.' | interpolate }}
</p>
```

I am getting the error

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'message' of undefined
>       at new  (http://localhost:8000/app/view2/view2.js:13:15)
>       at invoke (http://localhost:8000/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4560:17)
>       at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:8000/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4568:27)
>       at http://localhost:8000/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:9440:28
>       at link (http://localhost:8000/app/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js:985:26)
>       at invokeLinkFn (http://localhost:8000/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:9079:9)
>       at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:8000/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8566:11)
>       at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:8000/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:7965:13)
>       at publicLinkFn (http://localhost:8000/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:7845:30)
>       at boundTranscludeFn (http://localhost:8000/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:7983:16)

I think i am missing something.

Comment: Have you minified the code?

Comment: sorry i didn't get you minified means??

Comment: have you included all the js files in index.html?

Comment: yess everything is same i have not touched the index.html file of angular seed

Comment: how did you map that this view should belong to this controller? did you use ng-controller? or you just configured it in route params? Please add complete code

Comment: use in view ng-controller = View2Ctrl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you it is  minified  code then make this change before minification

```
.controller('View2Ctrl', ['$scope',function($scope) {   // note $scope added
$scope.message='hello every one';

}]);
```

Comment: or you can use `.controller('View2Ctrl', function($scope) {
$scope.message='hello every one';
});`, if you are not going to minify the code.